# How to setup LDAP authentication in Airflow 2.0

Tags: security, authentication, ldap, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am currently attempting to setup LDAP integration with an existing LDAP server in Airflow. In the past, I have attempted making a cacert (ldap_ca.crt) and have followed [this guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/security.html?highlight=ldap) and [this guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/security.html).

When I start up Airflow I am presented with a login screen that does not accept any users on the LDAP server and simply clears the username/password box when attempting to sign in.

This is the current code in my webserver_config.py (I have also tried making edits to airflow.cfg without success):

```py
# The authentication type
# AUTH_OID : Is for OpenID
# AUTH_DB : Is for database
# AUTH_LDAP : Is for LDAP
# AUTH_REMOTE_USER : Is for using REMOTE_USER from web server
# AUTH_OAUTH : Is for OAuth
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP

# Uncomment to setup Full admin role name
# AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'

# Uncomment to setup Public role name, no authentication needed
# AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Public'

# Will allow user self registration
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer"

# When using LDAP Auth, setup the ldap server
# AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://ldapserver.new"

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://ldap-server-name.org.com:999"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "CN=p_biaas,OU=Unix,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=aaa,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
#AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=aaa,DC=com"
#AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH= "OU=Unix,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=aaa,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=aaa,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "sAMAccountName"
#AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False

AUTH_LDAP_FIRSTNAME_FIELD = "givenName"
AUTH_LDAP_LASTTNAME_FIELD = "sn"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just made a video to set up Airflow 2.0 with LDAP.
I think it will help you a lot :)

[Configure AIRFLOW 2.0 with LDAP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6TygwvYdN0&ab_channel=MarcLamberti)

Comment: Left a comment on your Udemy course a while back regarding this and wanted to thank you for making the video!

Comment: Great videos indeed! Keep them coming!

Answer (score 2):

The two guides that you followed are for airflow v1.10.1 and v1.10.12. Airflow 2.0 introduces a host of changes to providers (akin to python 2 to python 3).

As a start please refer to the current version of the [airflow docs on access control](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html)

If you have a working configuration of LDAP in 1.10.12, try upgrading to v 1.10.14 and then installing the [backport providers](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/#using-backport-providers-in-airflow-1-10) before following the recommended upgrade path.

Airflow has put out a [guide](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html) on upgrading to airflow 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same issue...

Are you using the configuration files generated by the previous version of Airflow?

I had a similar configuration of LDAP (like you have) but it was not working with old configuration files.

Then I generated a brand new config by Airflow 2.0.1, passed in my old LDAP configuration and it worked.

Maybe it is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `webserver_config.py` configuration for Airflow 2.2.2 to connect IBM Bluepages LDAP. It is based on Marc's answer.

The only difference is to set the default role to the `Viewer` for new users. User with `Public` role only after login sees a weird page that looks like something going wrong.

```
import os
from airflow import configuration as conf
from airflow.www.fab_security.manager import AUTH_LDAP

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# The SQLAlchemy connection string.
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN')
# Flask-WTF flag for CSRF
CSRF_ENABLED = True
# AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = 'ldaps://bluepages.ibm.com:636'

# search configs
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = 'ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com'
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = 'mail'
AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED = True
# username and password to login IBM Bluepages 
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = 'uid=<<ibm user uid>>,c=us,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = '<<ibm user password>>'

# Will allow user self registration
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Viewer'
AUTH_LDAP_FIRSTNAME_FIELD = "givenName"
AUTH_LDAP_LASTNAME_FIELD = "sn"
AUTH_LDAP_EMAIL_FIELD = "mail"


# ----------------------------------------------------
# Theme CONFIG
# ----------------------------------------------------
# Flask App Builder comes up with a number of predefined themes
# that you can use for Apache Airflow.
# http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html#changing-themes
# Please make sure to remove "navbar_color" configuration from airflow.cfg
# in order to fully utilize the theme. (or use that property in conjunction with theme)
# APP_THEME = "bootstrap-theme.css"  # default bootstrap
# APP_THEME = "amelia.css"
# APP_THEME = "cerulean.css"
# APP_THEME = "cosmo.css"
# APP_THEME = "cyborg.css"
# APP_THEME = "darkly.css"
# APP_THEME = "flatly.css"
# APP_THEME = "journal.css"
# APP_THEME = "lumen.css"
# APP_THEME = "paper.css"
# APP_THEME = "readable.css"
# APP_THEME = "sandstone.css"
# APP_THEME = "simplex.css"
# APP_THEME = "slate.css"
# APP_THEME = "solar.css"
# APP_THEME = "spacelab.css"
# APP_THEME = "superhero.css"
# APP_THEME = "united.css"
# APP_THEME = "yeti.css"
```